# Cannot get Drawable from TypedArray in custom View on Android 4

Tags: android

I have declared some custom attributes for my custom view

```
<declare-styleable name="MenuItemView">
    <attr name="item_icon" format="reference" />
    <attr name="item_title_color" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

When I create the view, I obtain the styled attributes. I have tried both context.obtainStyledAttributes and context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes

```
public MenuItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView(context, context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.MenuItemView,
            0, 0));
}

public MenuItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initView(context, context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.MenuItemView,
            defStyleAttr, 0));
}
```

And then I try to get the drawable

```
public void initView(Context context, TypedArray a) {
    inflate(context, R.layout.menu_item, this);

    this.title = findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    this.icon = findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);

    try {
        title.setTextColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.MenuItemView_item_title_color, getResources().getColor(R.color.midnight_black)));
        Drawable iconDrawable = a.getDrawable(context, R.styleable.MenuItemView_item_icon);
        ...
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

}
```

On my phone, everything works fine, but on Android 4, it just says

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_profile_circle.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08012b
```

I found a very hacky way around this issue by switching the attribute type from a reference to a string and then doing this bit of nastiness

```
 String indentifier = a.getString(R.styleable.MenuItemView_item_icon);
 indentifier = indentifier.replace(".xml", "").replace("res/drawable/", "");
 int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(indentifier, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
 Drawable iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just enough to get color and icon and set for your views!

```
    int titleColorId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MenuItemView_item_title_color, getResources().getColor(R.color.midnight_black));
    int iconId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MenuItemView_item_icon, -1);

    title.setTextColor(titleColorId);
    if (iconId != -1)
        icon.setImageResource(iconId);
```